# How to retrieve and customize Watermark in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm not sure if this is considered best practices or not, but I'm trying to figure out a way to customize the watermark for Dataflow. Similar to Flink's `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()`.

I'm aware of `timestampBy()`, I want to be able to able to retrieve the current watermark and apply some additional logic that is dependent on it. But I can't seem to find any way to retrieve the current watermark.

Answer (score 0):

In MillWhell there was a way to programmatically define your own watermark based on source implementation but with DataFlow it has it's own implementation to decide watermark. If you are defining your own custom input yes you can implement logic to take into account your source implementation to get the watermark.

Comment: Currently I am doing some logic to maintain my own, but I'm looking for a way to specifically retrieve the internal watermark.